# Angles in Matlab

Tags: matlab, angle

i need to calculate some expression for all angles from 0 to 90 degrees increments 10 degrees (of cause expression depends on some trigonometrical function). 
It looks like:

```
for alpha = 0:10:90
   func(alpha) = c * sin(alpha)
end
```

Who know how to work with degrees, tell, please

Comment: So like...[`sind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sind.html)?

Comment: Or `sin(alpha * pi/180)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
for 0:pi/18:pi/2
```

Comment: You could also just replace `sin` with `sind` and keep the loop indices the same.  That's the easier change.